# linux архивация bzip2 всех лог файлов кроме активного

Tags: логирование, архивация

Доброго дня форумчане у меня на производстве есть в папке куча файлов с расширением access*log в таком формате:
access.2017-01-*.log
.....
access.2017-01-06.log
access.2017-01-07.log
access.2017-01-08.log

Подскажите какой коммандой заархивировать все акссес логи кроме текущего чтобы не погубить процес обновления лог файлов и удалить при создании архива соответсвующего оригинала с помощью архиватора bzip2 ?

Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: А по каким признакам можно определить, какой из файлов логов "текущий"? С другой стороны - а в чём засада-то? текущий лог либо недоступен, либо будет неполным, что поправится завтрашним бэкапом.

Comment: например как-нибудь грепнуть access.2017-01-08.log и исключить его из обработки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /var/log/ -type f -mtime +1 -name "access*.log" | xargs tar -jcvf archive.bz2
```

разберем.

- `/var/log/` где начать рекурсивный поиск
- `-type f` искать только файлы
- `-mtime +1` брать только те файлы, которые последний раз изменялись более суток назад. Это ключевой момент. Если файл лога сегодня менялся - наверно он ещё активен. А если он сутки уже не менялся - скорее всего либо это неактивный лог, либо сервер остановлен.
- `-name "access*.log"` дополнительное условие. можно по желанию
- `| xargs tar -jcvf archive.bz2` конвеером отправляем тару, который это запихает в bzip2

Если этих условий не хватит - воспользуйтесь [чудным инструментом](http://ru.clihelper.com/find/).

редактировал mtime

Comment: Не подскажите как разбить файлы чтобы каждый писался в отдельный архив? find . -type d -mtime +1 -exec tar -jcvf {}.tgz {} \; - не работает и не обрабатывает

Comment: `-type d` ищет каталоги.

Comment: find . -type f -mtime +2 -exec tar -jcvf {}.tgz {} --remove-files \;

Comment: Спасибо большущее еще раз!

Answer (score 1):

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
$eventDir = "C:\Users\dmitry.lakomkin\Desktop\Get-CollectorLog"
$beginDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$logs = (Get-ChildItem $eventDir | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -le $beginDate)}).FullName
Write-Host $beginDate
foreach ($log in $logs){
    Write-Host $log
}
Compress-Archive -Path $logs -Update -DestinationPath "C:\Users\dmitry.lakomkin\Desktop\Get-CollectorLog\test.zip"
 вот ps скрипт , который бэкапит все файлы кроме созданых в день запуска скрипта

Comment: Я тупица, простите, под unix в баше ищу способ это сделать(